# How RowSet works java?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset, rowset

I am trying to understand the internal workings of RowSet.

How does it set the properties data and create a connection?

```
RowSetFactory factory = RowSetProvider.newFactory();

JdbcRowSet jdbcRowSet = factory.createJdbcRowSet(); 

jdbcRowSet.setUrl( … );
jdbcRowSet.setUsername( … );
jdbcRowSet.setPassword( … );
jdbcRowSet.setCommand( … );

jdbcRowSet.execute();
```

Comment: Applications do not create RowSets.  JDBC drivers create RowSets, initialize those RowSets’ properties, and return them when executeQuery methods of Statements are called.

Comment: See the Javadoc for an explanation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/RowSet.html#execute() or ff you want to know the exact inner workings then take a look at the `execute` method within your IDE or in the openjke codebase

Comment: Which one? `RowSet` is an interface. It doesn’t have any workings at all.

Comment: Before posting here, read Oracle’s [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/RowSet.html) and [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to look at the default implementation [`com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk21u/blob/master/src/java.sql.rowset/share/classes/com/sun/rowset/JdbcRowSetImpl.java).

This class has a method [`connect()`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk21u/blob/master/src/java.sql.rowset/share/classes/com/sun/rowset/JdbcRowSetImpl.java#L612) that establishes the connection.

It does this in one of three ways:

- if the object was initialized with an SQL connection it returns that connection
- if the object has a datasource name it uses that name to lookup a datasource
- if the object has an url set it uses the `java.sql.DriverManager` to establish a connection to that url

No magic here, it does the same things that you would do if you were to open a connection yourself.

Comment: Additional note:The existing bundled implementation has not been well-maintained, and has significant limitations.